# getting data from custom ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview

In a custom ListView , I want to send all data to somewhere. But I am unable to get the respective row data.
Here is my code..

```
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

public class Question {
    int current = NONE; // hold the answer picked by the user, initial is NONE(see below)
    public static final int NONE = 1000; // No answer selected
    public static final int ANSWER_YES_SELECTED = 0; // Yes answer selected
    public static final int ANSWER_NO_SELECTED = 1; // Yes answer selected

    public int getCurrent() {
        return current;
    }

    public void setCurrent(int current) {
        this.current = current;
    }

    private String question;
    private RadioButton radioYes;
    private RadioButton radioNo;
    private EditText editResponse;
    RadioGroup radio_group;
    private Question(){
        super();

    }

    public Question(String title,RadioButton r1,RadioButton r2, EditText e1,RadioGroup radio_group) {
        super();
        this.radio_group=radio_group;
        this.question = title;
        this.radioYes=r1;
        this.radioNo=r2;
        this.editResponse=e1;



    }

    public Question(String title,RadioButton r1,RadioButton r2, EditText e1) {
        super();

        this.question = title;
        this.radioYes=r1;
        this.radioNo=r2;
        this.editResponse=e1;
    }

    public Question (String q){
        super();
        this.question=q;


    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public RadioButton getRadioYes() {
        return radioYes;
    }

    public void setRadioYes(RadioButton radioYes) {
        this.radioYes = radioYes;
    }

    public RadioButton getRadioNo() {
        return radioNo;
    }

    public void setRadioNo(RadioButton radioNo) {
        this.radioNo = radioNo;
    }

    public EditText getEditResponse() {
        return editResponse;
    }

    public void setEditResponse(EditText editResponse) {
        this.editResponse = editResponse;
    }

    public RadioGroup getRadio_group() {
        return radio_group;
    }

    public void setRadio_group(RadioGroup radio_group) {
        this.radio_group = radio_group;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Question [question=" + question + ", radioYes=" + radioYes
                + ", radioNo=" + radioNo + ", editResponse=" + editResponse.getText()
                + ", radio_group=" + radio_group + "]";
    }
}
```

My AdapterClass

```
public class QuestionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Question>{

    Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    Question[] data = null;
    final String[] text;
    int[] chkId=null;


    public QuestionAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Question[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        text=new String[data.length];
        chkId=new int[data.length];
        for (String s: text) {
            s="";

        }



    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final HashMap<Integer, Integer> checkeddMap= new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        View row = convertView;
        final QuestionHolder holder;

        final int pos=position;


        //  System.out.println("Position is "+position);

        if(row == null)
        {
            holder = new QuestionHolder();

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();          
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder.txtquestion = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtquestion);
            holder.radioYes = (RadioButton)row.findViewById(R.id.radioYes);
            holder.radioNo= (RadioButton)row.findViewById(R.id.radioNo);
            holder.editResponse=(EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.editResponse);
            holder.radio_group=(RadioGroup)row.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
            //holder.editResponse.setText(data[position].getEditResponse().toString());


            row.setTag(holder);



        }
        else

        {
            holder = (QuestionHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Question question = data[position];
        holder.txtquestion.setText(question.getQuestion());


        holder.editResponse.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                text[pos] =((EditText)v).getText().toString();
            }
        });

        holder.editResponse.setText(text[pos]);

        //  System.out.println(position+"Position");



        holder.radio_group.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            }
        });


        holder.radio_group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("In OnCheckedChaned Listener.");
                arg0.setTag(pos);
                Question element=data[pos];
                //  System.out.println("Tag of radio Group= "+(Integer)arg0.getTag());
                switch (checkedId) {

                case R.id.radioYes:
                    element.current=Question.ANSWER_YES_SELECTED;
                    checkeddMap.put(pos, data[pos].current);    
                    break;
                case R.id.radioNo:
                    element.current=Question.ANSWER_NO_SELECTED;
                    checkeddMap.put(pos, data[pos].current);    

                    break;
                case -1:
                    element.current=Question.NONE;

                }
            }
        });






        if (data[pos].current != Question.NONE) {
            RadioButton r = (RadioButton) holder.radio_group.getChildAt(data[position].current);
            r.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            holder.radio_group.clearCheck(); // This is required because although the Question could have the current 
            // position to NONE you could be dealing with a previous row where
            // the user already picked an answer. 

        }




        return row;

    }


    static class QuestionHolder
    {
        TextView txtquestion;
        RadioButton radioYes;
        RadioButton radioNo;
        EditText editResponse;
        RadioGroup radio_group;
    }

}
```

And My MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Question myQue;
    private ListView listView1;
    private Button btn;
    private String[] str={"First Question","Second Question","Third Question","Fourth Question","Fifth Question","SIxth Question","Seventh Q","Eightth Q","Nine th Q", "Tenth Q" };
    ArrayList< Question> arrayList;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.a_securitylist);
        RadioButton r1 = null;
        RadioButton r2 = null;
        RadioGroup radio_group = null; 
        EditText e1 = null;
        Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);


        EditText e2;     
        RadioGroup rg= new RadioGroup(getApplicationContext());
        rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
        RadioButton rYes=new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());
        RadioButton rNo=new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());
        rYes.setHeight(10);
        rYes.setWidth(10);
        EditText etext= new EditText(getApplicationContext());
        etext.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 10)); 

        RadioGroup rg1= new RadioGroup(getApplicationContext());
        int p=0;
        final Question weather_data[] = new Question[]
                {
                new Question((p+1)+"."+str[0], r1, r2, etext, radio_group),
                new Question((p+2)+"."+str[01], r1, r2, etext, radio_group),
                new Question((p+3)+"."+str[02], r1, r2, etext, radio_group),
                new Question((p+4)+"."+str[03], r1, r2, etext, radio_group),
                new Question((p+5)+"."+str[04], r1, r2, etext, radio_group),
                new Question((p+6)+"."+str[05], r1, r2, etext, radio_group),
                new Question((p+6)+"."+str[06], r1, r2, etext, radio_group),

                new Question((p+7)+"."+str[07], r1, r2, etext, radio_group),

                new Question((p+8)+"."+str[8], r1, r2, etext, radio_group),

                new Question((p+9)+"."+str[9], r1, r2, etext, radio_group)




                };

        QuestionAdapter adapter = new QuestionAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.listview_item_row, weather_data);


        listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.securityListView);
        listView1.setClickable(false);
        View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
        listView1.addHeaderView(header);
        View footer = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_footer_row, null);
        listView1.addFooterView(footer);
        Button btnSubmit=(Button)(footer.findViewById(R.id.submit));
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        System.out.println(listView1.getParent().toString());




        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("In Footer OnClick");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Footer Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                System.out.println(listView1.getChildCount()); // Child count is 4. but my list view has 10 items.

                System.out.println(listView1.getChildAt(2).findViewById(R.id.radio_group));

                // Working 
                //      System.out.println("Cheked Radio button at 0"+((RadioGroup)listView1.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.radio_group)).getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                //      System.out.println("Cheked Radio button at 01"+((RadioGroup)listView1.getChildAt(1).findViewById(R.id.radio_group)).getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                //      System.out.println("Cheked Radio button at 02"+((RadioGroup)listView1.getChildAt(2).findViewById(R.id.radio_group)).getCheckedRadioButtonId());

                // Not Working
                //  System.out.println("Cheked Radio button at 03"+((RadioGroup)listView1.getChildAt(3).findViewById(R.id.radio_group)).getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                //  System.out.println("Cheked Radio button at 04"+((RadioGroup)listView1.getChildAt(4).findViewById(R.id.radio_group)).getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                //  System.out.println("Cheked Radio button at 05"+((RadioGroup)listView1.getChildAt(5).findViewById(R.id.radio_group)).getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                //  System.out.println("Cheked Radio button at 06"+((RadioGroup)listView1.getChildAt(6).findViewById(R.id.radio_group)).getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                //  System.out.println("Cheked Radio button at 07"+((RadioGroup)listView1.getChildAt(7).findViewById(R.id.radio_group)).getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                //System.out.println(((Question)(listView1.getItemAtPosition(0))).radio_group.toString());

            }
        });

    }               

}
```

I want all data to be get on onclicklister of btnSumbit...

Comment: all data means what???

Comment: What data you want to get? Your list view data is already stored in your array.

Comment: I want to get checkedRadiobutton Id and the text from Edit Text. But cant find the way.

Answer (score 0):

Override a method getItem() in QuestionAdapter

```
@Override
public Question getItem(int position) {     
      return data[position];
}
```

if you don't have adapter then get your updated adapter by using

```
adapter = listview1.getAdapter();
```

now, get your data by using

```
Question question1 = adapter.getItem(1);
Question question2 = adapter.getItem(2);
```

and u can also get radiogroups by using :

```
RadioGroup radio1 = question1.getRadio_group();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. simply override following methods in Adapter class..

```
public String[] getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public int[] getChkId() {
        return chkId;
    }
```

And from your activity you can call them as-

```
adapter.getText();
adapter.getchkId();
```

will return array id string and ids.
That was so simple. Thanks all.